# Lodash GroupBy won't group array object

Tags: angular, lodash

I have an object array with 3 items but lodash is not working.  I have as the import:

```js
import * as _ from 'lodash';
```

I then have

```js
let customers = customerAll.map(cust => ({ CustId: cust.CustId, Comment: cust.comment}));
```

This has 3 array items they are all the same data in this case.

I tried doing `_.groupBy(customers);` this did not work.
Tried `_(customers).groupBy("CustId");` also did not work.

What am I doing wrong and how do i get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the method wrong it should look like this

```
let customersGrouped = _.groupBy(customers, 'CustId');
```

here is an example of the method working

```js
let customers = [
 {
   CustId: 1,
   Comment: 'test'
 },
 {
   CustId: 1,
   Comment: 'test'
 },
 {
   CustId: 2,
   Comment: 'test'
 },
 {
   CustId: 2,
   Comment: 'test'
 },
 {
   CustId: 13,
   Comment: 'test'
 }
];

console.log(_.groupBy(customers, 'CustId'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Still is not working it looks like this it hits the createAggregator function:

 function createAggregator(setter, initializer) {
      return function(collection, iteratee) {
        var func = isArray(collection) ? arrayAggregator : baseAggregator,
            accumulator = initializer ? initializer() : {};

        return func(collection, setter, getIteratee(iteratee, 2), accumulator);
      };
    }

I see in the debugger:

Object:  1234: (3) then the 3 array items.  The 1234 is the CustId

Comment: I think I need both fields how do I add both?

Comment: please update your question with your complete code example, an example of your object and an example of your desired result